# Pass and Assign multi-dim array

Tags: c#

I have already pass a multi-dim array as an argument; however, I don't know what's the best way to assign it to a new multi-dim array (a new one)

example:

```
double[, , , ,] results;
object[,] scales;    
public plot(double[, , , ,] x, object[,] y)
    {
        results= x;
        scales = y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [Passing array using ref and out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Your code :

```
double[,,,,] results;
object[,] scales;
public void Plot(ref double[,,,,] x, ref object[,] y)
{
   results = x;
   scales = y;
}
```

The difference between **ref** and **out** is **out** of parameter of array type the initialization of array is not required before passing to parameters; by contrast, **ref** is need the initialization of array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "a new one". If it means to assign the array inside variable 'x' to result, you are doing perfectly fine. But if you mean to create a new copy of 'x' you can use [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone.aspx) function:

```
double[,,,,] results;
object[,] scales;
public plot(double[, , , ,] x, object[,] y)
{
    results = (double[, , , ,])x.Clone();
    scales = (object[,])y.Clone();
}
```